# Is it possible to have multiple bevel objects along a curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm wondering if it's possible to define multiple bevel objects along a curve and have Blender interpolate between the bevels like keyframes.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, this isn't supported, nor do I think it's coming in any near future.

It probably wouldn't sit very well with Blender, since it's a mesh based. This would be more suited for NURBS based modeling tools or CAD software.

Closest thing I've ever seen is [BSurfaces Addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Bsurfaces_1.5) but it's not a very good solution.

Comment: that addon looks hella cool

Comment: why cant you convert the two different shapes into meshes and interpolate between the two shapes?

Comment: You can but it's far from a flexible or maintainable workflow. You have to convert to mesh, and it only works well for the same number of vertex if they differ or are in great number it will start causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

If the two bevel object curves have the same amount of vertices then yes.
Just convert the two curves into meshes and interpolate between them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think you get the question... (I might be wrong), I'm pretty sure that the OP means having a bevel shape change along a curve, so like a circle turning into a square. Could be wrong, but that's how I interpreted it.

Comment: I give example with square curve object interpolated with circle curve object

Comment: Yes I don't think this is what the user was asking about. I believe he wants to have different bevel shapes along the same curve