# Double beveled curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

[image: two different bevels above my curve]

I was wondering: is it possible to assign two bevels instead of one to the geometry of a curve, and maybe "warp" through them using weights?

Basically I have a loop curve that has a circular bevel (above curve, left), but at certain points it should gradually become an oval shape (above curve, right, selected) (or whatever shape i decide to bevel it with).

Thanks for the wisdom, peace

Comment: could you please show a drawing or screenshot to make it more understandable?

Comment: it looks like it is not possible except if you convert your curve to mesh and make a bridge for example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55257/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-bevel-objects-along-a-curve

Comment: ok thanks. I think it'd be a pretty useful feature for the future

Comment: maybe you could make your mesh shape straight with the shape morphing you want, then give it a cuve modifier to bend it. I mean if it's ok for you if it's a mesh and not a curve...